# knitr removes "before.plot.new" hooks

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, hook, knitr

Tried setting a permanent option using `before.plot.new` hooks in `plot.new` function. It works for plotting on screen and in various file types. However the settings are ignored in r-markdown.

Here is a small example changing the direction of axis labels with `las`:

```
hook <- getHook("before.plot.new")
hook$par <- function() par(las=1)
setHook("before.plot.new", hook, "replace")

plot(1)
```

[image: img1]

However from within r-markdown and after `knit("markdown.md")`:

````
```{r}
hook <- getHook("before.plot.new")
hook$par <- function() par(las=1)
setHook("before.plot.new", hook, "replace")

plot(1)
```
````

[image: img2]

However if we do the same using another hook `plot.new` - everything seems to be working as expected.

Does `knitr` wipe the contents of `before.plot.new` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a design decision in `r-lib` `evaluate` package. Already changed in the newest version.

Here is the relevant issue on GitHub repository for more details: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1684